# Как обратиться к компоненту JPanel в Java?

Tags: java

Есть класс MyFrame, в котором описано создание фрейма, и в этом классе создаются компонент JPanel.

И есть класс Example, в котором создаётся Button, и затем я хочу добавить этот Button на JPanel. Но выскакивает ошибка: panel cannot be resolved. В чём ошибка?

```
class MyFrame extends JFrame
{
    public MyFrame()
    {
        setSize(300, 400);
        setTitle("Example");

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(Color.green);
        add(panel);
     }
}

class Example
{
    public Example()
    {
        JButton Button = new JButton("oooooo");
        panel.add(Button); //в этой строке показывает ошибку
    }
}
```

Comment: А откуда класс Example должен знать о локальной переменной `panel` в конструкторе `MyFrame`?

Answer (score 2):

panel в классе Example получается локальной переменной, которая до этого не создана. Я вижу такие варианты: либо передавать в конструктор Example ссылку на panel и вызывать его из конструктора класса MyFrame(можно ещё сделать метод getPanel() в классе MyFrame, который будет возвращать ссылку на панель, саму панель придётся сделать полем объекта), либо создавать и добавлять кнопки в конструкторе класса MyFrame. Ещё вариант - сделать Example внутренним классом MyFrame, а panel сделать полем объекта MyFrame. Тогда, если не ошибаюсь, из внутреннего класса будет доступ к объекту panel Поправьте меня если я не прав или не знаю ещё какого-либо способа.

Comment: Проще panel объявить как public static поле в MyFrame.

Comment: О, не подумал об этом, спасибо. Привык поля приватными делать.

Comment: @lightcyber , а как объявить это в рамках моих классов?

Comment: Перед конструктором появится строчка public static JPanel panel, а в конструкторе заместо JPanel panel = new JPanel(); будет this.panel = new JPanel();
А обращаться так: MyFrame.panel

Comment: Yuri_Prime, перед каким конструктором? добавляю ошибки выскакивают

Comment: class MyFrame extends JFrame
{
public static JPanel panel;
    public MyFrame()
    {
        setSize(300, 400);
        setTitle("Example");

        this.panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(Color.green);
        add(panel);
     }
}

Comment: @Yuri_Prime, я всё сделал как вы сказали, но кнопка не добавляется
пишу MyFrame.panel1.add(Button); и ничего нет

Comment: В классе Example:

        JButton Button = new JButton("oooooo");
        MyFrame.panel.add(Button); //в этой строке показывает ошибку

И вызывать конструктор Example нужно после конструктора MyFrame, иначе ссыпется программа с NullPointerException.

Comment: @Yuri_Prime, и ещё такой вопрос: я в классе Example пытаюсь вызвать диалоговое окно JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Hello");
Но компилятор ругается на frame. не видит его, в чём дело?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй так:

```
class MyFrame extends JFrame{
    public static final JPanel panel;

    public MyFrame(){
        setSize(300, 400);
        setTitle("Example");
        panel = new JPanel();      
        panel.setBackground(Color.green);
        add(panel);
    }
}

class Example{
    public Example(){
        JButton Button = new JButton("oooooo");
        MyFrame.panel.add(Button); 
    }
}
```